# Java String Switch counting votes

Tags: java

I've looked at several examples of using the switch statement with a string, and haven't been successful in making mine work. I'm just trying to count the number of votes for A or B, and when I compile this, it doesn't return any errors. When I run it though, I get a runtime error:
Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Votes {

   private String s_numVoters, singleVote;
   private static int v_numVoters = 0, v_countVotes = 0, aCount = 0, bCount = 0, invalidCount = 0;

   public int m_numVoters() {

      s_numVoters = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many voters will be voting today?");
      int v_numVoters = Integer.parseInt(s_numVoters);

      return v_numVoters;
   }

   public void countVotes(String[] votes) {
      do {

         singleVote = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Voting system. Please, enter:\nA - To vote for candidate A.\nB - To vote for candidate B.\n"
                                                   + "Z - To finish the voting process.\nAnything else will be considered as an INVALID vote.");

         switch (votes[0]) {
            case "A":
               aCount = aCount + 1;
               break ;
            case "B":
               bCount = bCount + 1;
               break ;
            default :
               invalidCount = invalidCount + 1;
         }
      } while (singleVote != "Z" || (aCount + bCount + invalidCount) <= v_numVoters);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Votes newVotes = new Votes();
      newVotes.m_numVoters();
      newVotes.countVotes(args);
      System.out.println(aCount + " " + bCount + " " + invalidCount);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could we know what the runtime error is?

Comment: Yes! I tried to add it before, but it was read as possible code, so I had to remove it in order to post the question. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Votes.countVotes(Votes.java:22)
 at Votes.main(Votes.java:39)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem comes down to this block of code...

```
public void countVotes(String[] votes) {
    do {

        singleVote = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Voting system. Please, enter:\nA - To vote for candidate A.\nB - To vote for candidate B.\n"
                + "Z - To finish the voting process.\nAnything else will be considered as an INVALID vote.");

        switch (votes[0]) {
            case "A":
                aCount = aCount + 1;
                break;
            case "B":
                bCount = bCount + 1;
                break;
            default:
                invalidCount = invalidCount + 1;
        }
    } while (singleVote != "Z" || (aCount + bCount + invalidCount) <= v_numVoters);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Votes newVotes = new Votes();
    newVotes.m_numVoters();
    newVotes.countVotes(args);
    System.out.println(aCount + " " + bCount + " " + invalidCount);
}
```

which is generating a ...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at javaapplication195.Votes.countVotes(Votes.java:29)
    at javaapplication195.Votes.main(Votes.java:46)
```

The "main" cause is...

```
switch (votes[0]) {
```

Because you're passing in `args` coming from `main`, so unless you've actually passed in any command line arguments, this will be empty.

This raises the next question, why!?  You've completed ignored the input from the user

So, instead, the above could be changed to...

```
public void countVotes() {
    do {
        // A local variable should be more useful here
        singleVote = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Voting system. Please, enter:\nA - To vote for candidate A.\nB - To vote for candidate B.\n"
                + "Z - To finish the voting process.\nAnything else will be considered as an INVALID vote.");

        switch (singleVote) {
            case "A":
                aCount = aCount + 1;
                break;
            case "B":
                bCount = bCount + 1;
                break;
            default:
                invalidCount = invalidCount + 1;
        }
    } while (singleVote != "Z" || (aCount + bCount + invalidCount) <= v_numVoters);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Votes newVotes = new Votes();
    newVotes.m_numVoters();
    newVotes.countVotes();
    System.out.println(aCount + " " + bCount + " " + invalidCount);
}
```

But a better solution would be...

```
switch (singleVote) {
    case "A":
    case "a":
        aCount = aCount + 1;
        break;
    case "B":
    case "b":
        bCount = bCount + 1;
        break;
    default:
        invalidCount = invalidCount + 1;
}
```

Or use `singleVote.toUpperCase()`

```
singleVote = singleVote.toUpperCase()
switch (singleVote) {
    case "A":
        aCount = aCount + 1;
        break;
    case "B":
        bCount = bCount + 1;
        break;
    default:
        invalidCount = invalidCount + 1;
}
```

which would then allow you to fix the next issue in your code...

```
do {
    //...
} while (singleVote != "Z" || (aCount + bCount + invalidCount) <= v_numVoters);
```

This is not how you do `String` comparisons in Java, you should be using `!"Z".equals(singleVote)` or something similar.

And finally...

```
public int m_numVoters() {

    s_numVoters = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many voters will be voting today?");
    int v_numVoters = Integer.parseInt(s_numVoters);

    return v_numVoters;
}
```

You're shadowing the `v_numVoters`, this means that when you do `(aCount + bCount + invalidCount) <= v_numVoters`, is `0`.

Change it something more like...

```
public int m_numVoters() {

    s_numVoters = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many voters will be voting today?");
    v_numVoters = Integer.parseInt(s_numVoters);

    return v_numVoters;
}
```

Comment: i think it should be `switch (singleVote.toUpperCase())`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh The reason I didn't do that was because they used the variable in the exit condition, it would be better to use `singleVote = singleVote.toUpperCase()` which I seem to have skipped and used the old code - I've updated it

Comment: yup.. that's there too though it's going extra mile(good thing) but the dialog says the input should be uppercase values and seems like user previously was doing it with `args` and currently not(missed that)

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh When did you ever know a user to follow directions :D

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! I am pretty much a beginner, as you can tell, and the references (including textbook) I've been given do not explain the switch statement very well at all. This really helps a ton.